# external USB drive getting mounted as ro

Tags: usb, mount, mac

mount displays:

```
/dev/sdc2 on /media/My Book type hfsplus (ro,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)
```

Is there a way to mount this as rw, and copy data.

This was working with Mac OSX, and on Mac its no loger getting mounted, and on ubuntu, i see it as being mounted as read only.

Answer (score 0):

You can remount it `rw`:

```
umount /dev/sdc2
udisks --mount /dev/sdc2 --mount-options rw
```

As for why it is being mounted `ro`, you should consult the syslog.